# How to obtain and apply service packs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am having the same problem as described in [this jira about CORS headers](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2546). It has been fixed, but the release is showing as Fixed with r205117 (the commit).

Is there a way to obtain service packs, or do I have to build the product myself ?

---

As @Asela said you can build this fix for yourself.

Personally I found the [instructions listed in the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Building+from+Source) rather lacking so thought I'd post an update on how I managed to patch it. Once I found a way to get this to work it was simple, but took a while to discover how to.

#### Download source

As per docs, but be aware it's a 4G+ download

```
svn checkout https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk11 ~/wso2.chunk11
```

#### Patch code

cd to `~/wso2.chunk11/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/1.2.2/`

edit `src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/Utils.java`

#### Build JAR

I used `mvn clean compile install`

#### Patch product

1. cd to product home, in my case `~/wso2am-1.7.0`
2. cd to patches `./repository/components/patches/`
3. mkdir and cd for the patch, in my case `mkdir patch0009 ; cd patch0009`
4. copy in the new jar there `cp ~/wso2.chunk11/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/1.2.2/target/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.2.jar .`
5. start the product and the patch should apply.

#### Test patch

Assuming you've added the '*' to `~/wso2am-1.7.0/repository/conf/api-manager.xml`:

```
<Access-Control-Allow-Origin>*</Access-Control-Allow-Origin>
```

You can just curl an API and see the correct header:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Origin: http://somewhere.com' http://192.168.1.64:8280/myApi
```

An check the correct domain setting is returned:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed in the APIM 1.8.0 which has not been released yet.  Therefore you may need to wait for 1.8.0 official release. I think,  if you can obtain support from WSO2, they would give it as a patch. If not, you have following options.

1. You can find the source change with `r205117` and apply it to the older APIM version (say APIM 1.7.0).  To do that you need to build the relevant jar file with above diff. Ordinal source for jar file can be found at [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/1.2.2/) and  Source diff can be found at [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/Njy1ex9wLHGuiegVxDeZ).  You can apply the source diff and build the jar file, then replace the orignal jar file which can be found in the APIM 1.7.0
2. You can build the 1.8.0 product by yourself.  It would be little bit hard to build all the product and get a new pack of 1.8.0.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Asela. I found it a little more tricky than expected, but in the end managed to find a way that worked. I'll add it to the question so I can format it properly.